# How to delete file programmatically from sd card in android 4.4 and above

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android-external-storage

Actually I am making an app in which I can list all data present in external sd card and can delete a file. But because in android 4.4 and above we cannot write to external sd card. Please help me get out of this..

Answer (score -3):

First of all update your manifest.xml with following code:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE />`

Then write:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

where filePath is the path of the file you want to delete

for example,

/sdcard/myDirectory/myfile.txt

Comment: the files cannot be deleted from sd card above lollipop. No third party app is having access to write on sdcard. But I dont know how apps like es file explorer can delete and move file from sdcard.